# Java: Splitting a string by whitespace when there is a variable number of whitespaces between words?

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following:

```
String string = "1-50  of 500+";
String[] stringArray = string.split(" ");
```

Printing out all the elements in this array gives me the following:

```
Element 1: 1-50
Element 2:  of 500+
```

How can I get it to split elements by the requirement that there is at least one whitespace between the words?

In other words, I want my elements to be:

```
Element 1: 1-50
Element 2: of
Element 3: 500+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\\s+` to split on spaces even if they are more.

```
String string = "1-50  of 500+";
String[] stringArray = string.split("\\s+");

for (String str : stringArray)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Full example: http://ideone.com/CFVr6N

***EDIT:***

If you also want to split on tabs, change the regex to `\\s+|\\t+` and it detects both spaces and tabs as well.

Comment: Tab is considered whitespace so it belongs to `\s` class. There is no need to add special case for it.

Answer (score 7):

With guava [`Splitter`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter):

```
package com.stackoverflow.so19019560;

import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.List;

public class Foo {

    private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE).omitEmptyStrings();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String string = "1-50  of \t\n500+";
        final List<String> elements = Lists.newArrayList(SPLITTER.split(string));

        // output
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Element %d: %s", i + 1, elements.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Element 1: 1-50
Element 2: of
Element 3: 500+
```

Comment: this is the fastest one I've tried so far, much faster than `Splitter.onPattern("\\s+")` or the other solutions posted here, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Plus 1 for the package name.

Comment: @DavidNedrow you don't want to see my "SO" project :p

Answer (score 5):

You can split using regex

```
string.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String string = "1-50  of 500+";
    String[] stringArray = string.split("\\s+");
    for (String str : stringArray)
      {
        System.out.println(str);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to spilt the String.

```
String[] stringArray = string.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: I might add I am retrieving the data from an HTML page... so maybe that space that I am seeing in the output is actually some other sort of whitespace?

Comment: try to use String#trim() function on every string from an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your Program is correct but you put two space after `1-50`. So Its giving you that output. Remove one space and you are done. No need to change the code. But if there is a two space then you should use `string.split("\\s+")`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] stringArray = string.split(" +");
```

instead of

```
String[] stringArray = string.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the space problem, after splitting, you can use `.trim()` to remove the white space.

Something like this should work.

```
for(int x=0; x<stringArray.length(); x++){
    stringArray[x] = stringArray[x].trim();
}
```