# How to split a string or get the right text from string

Tags: java

I need some help to split up a string. Right now, my string contains this:

```
"RM 8 Text"
```

Now I only want Text to be printed in my string builder using append, how do I get rid of the RM 8 in the start of the string?

Right now I have done it this way, but there has to be an easier way.

```
String[] lines = fromServer.split("\\s+");
String line2 = lines[2];    
logbuilder.append(line2);
```

Comment: `logbuilder.append(fromServer.substring(5)`

Comment: @staticx OP already did it. Looking for better way,.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: It's still a duplicate.

Comment: @staticx Nope. I don't think so :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Yep, it is. Check Meta for an explanation.

Comment: @staticx I'm not that much active on meta. Could you please attach the post that explains it ?

Comment: @staticx It's not a duplicate. `duplicate` means that the OP is asking the same thing as the other question. That's not the case, the OP already knows how to split a string by spaces, he's simply searching for an easier solution.

Comment: @BackSlash: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12184/139168

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12184/139168

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Uhm, "if you are likely to get similar answers.." yes, yes, it is :)

Comment: @staticx ***If the question is similar and it is likely to NOT get the exact same answer, you likely do not have a duplicate.*** That's a specific case, so the OP won't get similar answers, but answers applied to ***his*** scenario. To me it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @staticx Again, OP know how to split and he already did it. OP looking for a fair way.

Comment: @BackSlash: If you say so, it's a dupe. It's likely to get the same answer.

Comment: Plus, here are some more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600876/split-string-by-space-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059993/how-to-split-a-string-or-get-the-right-text-from-string?noredirect=1#comment35237287_23059993 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019560/java-splitting-a-string-by-whitespace-when-there-is-a-variable-number-of-whites

how many times are we going to answer the same thing?

Comment: @staticx **Splitting string by " " != getting last word after split with " "**

Comment: @Pixel could you please consider changing of title, which exactly reflect the problem.

Comment: @staticx To me it's not a duplicate, we are not simply talking about splitting a string by spaces, we are talking about getting the last part of a string in an easier way than splitting (If you read the question, you'll see that the OP is asking for a better way to solve his scenario ***without*** splitting).

Comment: @BackSlash: Using that logic, then here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672806/java-fastest-way-to-get-last-word-in-a-string :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming  that is standard format

```
String lastWord = fromServer.substring(fromServer.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply replace the `RM 8`.

```
String content = fromServer.replaceAll("RM 8", "");

logBuilder.append(content);
```

Comment: Or `logBuilder.append(fromServer.replceAll("RM 8", ""));` ;)

Comment: I try to make my changes as close to OP code as possible. Hence the two line solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll(".*\\s+(\\S+)$", "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code sample,

```
String abc = "RM 8 Text" ;
int a = abc.lastIndexOf(" ");
String xyz = abc.substring(a,abc.length());
System.out.println(xyz);
```